# have some pages of my Wordpress site sit on another domain

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, dns

My new client would like to have one main domain, lets call it `maindomain.com`.
The client offers multiple services that are pretty specific and not really related to each other. There are 4 services:

- service A
- service B
- service C
- service D

Now he has the idea to buy different domains for those services and map those pages to those domain. For example, I visit `maindomain.com`, there's:
 - maindomain.com/contact
 - maindomain.com/about-us
 - main-domain.com/approach
 - maindomain.com/services
those are all on the `maindomain.com`domain. Now from the navbar and the `maindomain.com/services` page, the user should be able to navigate to the single service pages. When the user click **Service A** from the services archive page, the user should go to `service-a.com`.

In other words, can I map some pages to a different domain like this huge webshop from the netherlands?
https://www.coolblue.nl/ (main domain)
https://www.laptopshop.nl/ (domain just for selling laptops)

How would this go SEO wise? My opinion says the service pages could get stronger because they have their own domain.

I've done some research and it looks like I can do this with the .htaccess file only, is this true?

**Edit to be more clear**
I would like to maintain the Wordpress installation from one single installation just like it was a regular one-domain Wordpress install.

Comment: as I understand you want that if user click on maindomain.com/services the user will redirect to the service-a.com

Comment: @RajKumarBhardwaj maindomain.com/services would be the archive page, from there I would like the different domains.

Comment: so I hope your page(SERVICE A) will be  a menu on your maindomain.com?

Comment: Sure, I will have a menu button called 'services' with the four services underneath it (submenu)

Comment: Ok, what you think about custom links from menu sections? you can create custom link and paste URL on which you want to redirect it

Comment: Yeah I know, but I would like to maintain the site from one install, just like it is a normal Wordpress installation.

Comment: is there nobody with any experience on this that can help me out?

Comment: what you mean by this "but I would like to maintain the site from one install,"  as i understood you want just click to service a from your menu and want to redirect it to servicea.com which is very simple , but you should have the website like servicea.com

Comment: What I mean buy this is if it is possible to install Wordpress on the main domain, and do something so the services single pages sit on external domains, did you see my example domains? What I would not prefer is to install Wordpress on 5 domains (main and 4 services domains) and maintain 5 installs just so the 4 services pages sit on an external domain. Can this be handled from one single installation?